# AH00526: Syntax error in PuTTy

Tags: phpmyadmin

Firstly, I am a non-techie.  I had a developer who helped me to build a website.  I currently host this with AWS.  A few days ago I realised that my website wasn't working at all (!) and I get a general error that the page cannot be reached.  I checked with AWS and my domain provider and all seems normal.  I then logged into putty, as my developer explained to me that I would need to add my IP address as a requirement if this changes, but I can see there is an error here.

Starting httpd: AH00526: Syntax error on line 24 of /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf:
Invalid command 'r', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

I can't find my developer as he has 'completed' his work, but now I can't figure out what this error is, and if it's reason that my site is down.

Can someone please help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your developer configured your webserver but had some little issues when typing. The error you're faced to is caused by an corrupted configuration file named **phpMyAdmin.conf**.
This file belongs to a software installed on your server to administrate MySQL-Databases.

As the error prompt says: **Syntax error on line 24 [..]: Invalid command 'r' [..]** the file contains a command which isn't understood by your webserver.

Maybe your developer just mistyped something when updating the config manually.

So what you can do:
Open the config-file with

```
nano /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpMyAdmin.conf
```

Scroll with the arrow-keys to line 24 and read it. Since you said that you're an non-IT-Guy you could post this part of your **config** to us and we have a look. Or you have to wait for your developer.

Comment: OMG thank you so much!!!!!!  Even I was able to fix this with your guidance!!!  My website is back up!!!!!!!!!  :-D